# How to quickly delete the lines in a file that contain items from a list in another file in BASH?

Tags: bash, optimization, sed

I have a file called `words.txt` containing a list of words. I also have a file called `file.txt` containing a sentence per line. I need to quickly delete any lines in `file.txt` that contain one of the lines from `words.txt`, but only if the match is found somewhere between `{` and `}`.

E.g. `file.txt`:

```
Once upon a time there was a cat.
{The cat} lived in the forest.
The {cat really liked to} eat mice.
```

E.g. `words.txt`:

```
cat
mice
```

Example output:

```
Once upon a time there was a cat.
```

Is removed because "cat" is found on those two lines and the words are also between `{` and `}`.

The following script successfully does this task:

```
while read -r line
do
    sed -i "/{.*$line.*}/d" file.txt
done < words.txt
```

This script is very slow. Sometimes `words.txt` contains several thousand items, so the while loop takes several minutes. I attempted to use the `sed -f` option, which seems to allow reading a file, but I cannot find any manuals explaining how to use this.

How can I improve the speed of the script?

Comment: First, stop using `sed -i` since you are doing an absurd amount of unnecessary IO.  Use the shell for manipulating the files instead of a half-baked non-portable and unnecessary option.  Then, use awk to read words.txt before going through file.txt in a single pass.

Comment: Which version of bash are you targeting?

Comment: Also -- you've given us an idea of the scale of `words.txt` (thousands-of-items at the max); what's the upper bound of `file.txt`? Will it fit comfortably in memory?

Comment: `words.txt` is never more than 20,000 lines and file.txt never seems to be more than 6000 lines, or 1 GB.

Answer (score 4):

An awk solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a["{[^{}]*"$0"[^{}]*}"]++;next}{for(i in a)if($0~i)next;b[j++]=$0}END{printf "">FILENAME;for(i=0;i in b;++i)print b[i]>FILENAME}' words.txt file.txt
```

It converts `file.txt` directly to have the expected output.

```
Once upon a time there was a cat.
```

Uncondensed version:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {
        a["{[^{}]*" $0 "[^{}]*}"]++
        next
    }
    {
        for (i in a)
            if ($0 ~ i)
                next
        b[j++] = $0
    }
    END {
        printf "" > FILENAME
        for (i = 0; i in b; ++i)
            print b[i] > FILENAME
    }
' words.txt file.txt
```

If files are expected to get too large that awk may not be able to handle it, we can only redirect it to stdout. We may not be able to modify the file directly:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {
        a["{[^{}]*" $0 "[^{}]*}"]++
        next
    }
    {
        for (i in a)
            if ($0 ~ i)
                next
    }
    1
' words.txt file.txt
```

Comment: +1; O(n+m), and written in awk, which is damned fast. Only thing I might change would be adding a whitespace-expanded / commented version for readability.

Comment: ...the memory-use costs might be worth mentioning, though.

Comment: My awk-based solution looks remarkably similar to your latest edit (sorry I didn't notice it before submitting), although I like yours better as it doesn't require the use of a flag. +1

Comment: @TomFenech No worries :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use grep to match 2 files like this:

```
grep -vf words.txt file.txt
```

Comment: That would work if not that I need to only remove lines where `{.*pattern.*}` is found.

Comment: the `-v` option makes it an invert match leaving only the lines that don't contain a match from words.txt

Answer (score 2):

In think that using the `grep` command should be way faster. By example:

```
grep -f words.txt -v file.txt
```

- The `f` option make grep use the `words.txt` file as matching patterns
- The `v` option reverse the matching, ie keeping files that do not match one of the patterns.

It doesn't solve the `{}` constraint, but that is easily avoidable, for example by adding the brackets to the pattern file (or in a temporary file created at runtime).

Comment: I can easily add `{` and `}` to the beginning and end of each line in `words.txt`, but it should allow for the space between the match, with `.*`, so I don't know how to add `.*` to the file.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work for you:

```
sed -e 's/.*/{.*&.*}/' words.txt | grep -vf- file.txt > out ; mv out file.txt
```

This basically just modifies the `words.txt` file on the fly and uses it as a word file for `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in two steps:

1. Wrap each word in `words.txt` with `{.*` and `.*}`:

   ```
    awk '{ print "{.*" $0 ".*}" }' words.txt > wrapped.txt
   ```
2. Use `grep` with inverse match:

   ```
    grep -v -f wrapped.txt file.txt
   ```

This would be particularly useful if `words.txt` is very large, as a pure-awk approach (storing all the entries of `words.txt` in an array) would require a lot of memory.

If would prefer a one-liner and would like to skip creating the intermediate file you could do this:

```
awk '{ print "{.*" $0 ".*}" }' words.txt | grep -v -f - file.txt
```

The `-` is a placeholder which tells `grep` to use `stdin`

---

#### update

If the size of `words.txt` isn't too big, you could do the whole thing in `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next}{p=1;for(i in a){if ($0 ~ "{.*" i ".*}") { p=0; break}}}p' words.txt file.txt
```

expanded:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$0]++; next }
     { 
         p=1
         for (i in a) {
             if ($0 ~ "{.*" i ".*}") { p=0; break }
         }
     }p' words.txt file.txt
```

The first block builds an array containing each line in `words.txt`. The second block runs for every line in `file.txt`. A flag `p` controls whether the line is printed. If the line matches the pattern, `p` is set to false. When the `p` outside the last block evaluates to true, the default action occurs, which is to print the line.

Comment: You're asserting that `grep -f patternfile` doesn't store the contents of `patternfile` in memory? How does it get away with that efficiently?

Comment: @Charles that's a fair point. To be honest, I don't know what would happen in that case. I've added an awk-based implementation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In pure native bash (4.x):

```
#!/bin/env bash4
# ^-- MUST start with a /bin/bash shebang, NOT /bin/sh

readarray -t words <words.txt          # read words into array
IFS='|'                                # use | as delimiter when expanding $*
words_re="[{].*(${words[*]}).*[}]"     # form a regex matching all words
while read -r; do                      # for each line in file...
  if ! [[ $REPLY =~ $words_re ]]; then # ...check whether it matches...
    printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"             # ...and print it if not.
  fi
done <file.txt
```

Native bash is somewhat slower than awk, but this still is a single-pass solution (`O(n+m)`, whereas the `sed -i` approach was `O(n*m)`), making it *vastly* faster than any iterative approach.

Comment: While it's nice that this is entirely in bash, I'm not sure this is going to be faster. Be curious to see a benchmark though.

Comment: @pgl, there's no question whatsoever that it'll be faster than the looped `sed -i` approach for nontrivial `words.txt` files.

Comment: @pgl, ...sure, bash itself is fairly slow as a shell (running this same script with ksh would go quite a lot faster, perhaps even competitive with awk... and it might actually be compatible with modern ksh92, but I haven't checked), but most of the reason bash _scripts_ are slow on a large scale is that they tend to be written to create unnecessary subshells, to run external programs unnecessarily, etc. This does none of those things.

Comment: Actually I think you're right, it would be faster. I think the grep approach might be even faster though.

Comment: @pgl, ...as in all things, it depends on how you measure. For small enough files, I'd expect startup time to dominate, and (presuming invocation within a shell that's already running) the native in-shell version to perform better. For larger files, yes, a single-pass grep will overtake this.